# Editing Data in an XLS with PHP then importing into mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import, xls

I am trying to import an XLS file into PHP, where I can then edit the information and import it into mySQL. I have never done anything related to this, so I am having a hard time grasping how to approach it.

I have looked at a few open source projects:

- PHP Excel Reader
- ExcelRead
- PHPExcel

None of these options perfectly fit what I want to do or maybe I just haven't gone deep enough into the documentation.

There are some things that needed to be taken into consideration. The XLS file cannot be converted into any other file format. This is being made for ease-of-access for nontechnical users. The XLS file is a report generated on another website that will have the same format (columns) every time.
For example, every XLS file with have the same amount of columns (this would be A1):

```
*ID   |Email   |First Name  |Last Name  |Paid    |Active   |State  |Country|*
```

But, there are more columns in the XLS file than what is going to be imported into the DB.
For example, the rows that are being imported (this would be A1):

```
*ID   |Email  |First Name  |Last Name  |Country*
```

I know one of two ways to do edit the data would be A. Use something like PHPExcel to read in the data, edit it, then send it to the DB or B. Use something like PHPExcel to convert the XLS to CSV, do a raw import into a temp table, edit the data, and insert it into the old table.

I have read a lot of the PHPExcel documentation but, it doesn't have anything on importing into a database and I don't really even know where to start with editing the XLS before or after importing.

I have googled a lot of keywords and mostly found results on how to read/write/preview XLS. I am looking for advice on the best way of doing all of these things in the least and simplest steps.

Comment: You would use PHP for all three steps. You would first import the excel data into *memory* using some PHP package (you mentioned some examples yourself). Store it in variables, and use PHP to manipulate it however you want. Then you would use the same PHP script to connect to the database and save the new data.

Comment: PHPExcel provides a full toolset for editing cell values, but unless you want to save the workbook again, why edit the cells and not simply change the extracted data before inserting it into MySQL. The documentation doesn't show you how to put the data in a database, because INSERT statements are covered by so much other documentation, but there are examples that show how to extract the data from your worksheets in various ways, including using the rowIterators.

Comment: @Mark Like I said, it is for nontechnical users, I don't want them to edit the workbook at all, because everyone has their own interpretation and that's how data gets corrupted.

Comment: @BenLee Have you used any of the listed packages before? If so, which one?

Comment: @user998328, I have not used any of these packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this article on using PHP-ExcelReader](http://devzone.zend.com/27/reading-and-writing-spreadsheets-with-php/), in particular the short section titled "Turning the Tables".

Any solution you have will end up looking like this:

1. Read a row from the XLS (requires an XLS reader)
2. Modify the data from the row as needed for your database.
3. Insert modified data into the database.

You seem to have this fixation on "Editing the data". This is just PHP--you get a value from the XLS reader, modify it with PHP code, then insert into the database. There's no intermediate file, you don't modify the XLS--it's just PHP.

This is a super-simple, untested example of the inner loop of the program you need to write. This is just to illustrate the general pattern.

```
$colsYouWant = array(1,2,3,4,8);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO data (id, email, fname, lname, country) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$sheet = $excel->sheets[0];
// the excel reader seems to index by 1 instead of 0: be careful!
for ($rowindex=2; $rowindex <= $sheet['numRows']; $rowindex++) {
    $xlsRow = $sheet['cells'][$rowindex];
    $row = array();
    foreach ($colsYouWant as $colindex) {
        $row[] = $xlsRow[$colindex];
    }
    // now let's "edit the row"
    // trim all strings
    $row = array_map('trim', $row);
    // convert id to an integer
    $row[0] = (int) $row[0];
    // capitalize first and last name
    // (use mb_* functions if non-ascii--I don't know spreadsheet's charset)
    $row[2] = ucfirst(strtolower($row[2]));
    $row[3] = ucfirst(strtolower($row[3]));

    // do whatever other normalization you want to $row

    // Insert into db:
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

Comment: I guess my fixation is based on the fact that I can't find any well written tutorials on how to edit the row before entry. That article seems to go into more detail than I have been able to find.

Comment: If you know PHP, you know how to edit a row before entry. e.g. `$valueForDb = trim($cellFromXls)`. There, you just edited.

Comment: I don't want to edit by cell, I want to edit by row. And I can't find documentation on how to call a row instead of a cell or record. I thought I explained that in my original post. I know PHP, it's not the issue. The problem is the inbetween I.E. the XLS reader. I am not clear on if it is even capable of being called by row.

Comment: If you want a "row", then just iterate cells by rowindex and columnindex and accumulate all cells with the same rowindex into an array. Excel doesn't have a strong concept of "rows" like databases. It has only cells with (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, I understand about excel, there's just not a better way to describe it. I will try that and hopefully post a solution

Comment: I have posted code with the general pattern you need since you seem to have trouble visualizing it. Other than write the program for you there isn't really any more help we can give.